# Jackson deserialization of lombok enhanced class: Why it does work and why it doesn't work?

Tags: jackson, lombok

Background: I found "dysfunctional" code in spring-admin project: "Cannot construct instance of Registration (no Creators, like default construct, exist)". So I wrote custom deserializer and report the issue. But report was rejected, since it allegedly works. And after retest it seems to work now. Does not make sense. So I would like to know **why** that code work.

But here is the catch. When I wrote similar test class, it does not work in my project. Even when I literally take the code of "now-working" Registration class, and try it in own project, is simply does not deserialize. And then, with practically identical class, it works. It doesn't make any sense.

https://github.com/codecentric/spring-boot-admin/blob/master/spring-boot-admin-server/src/main/java/de/codecentric/boot/admin/server/domain/values/Registration.java

Following post explains how lombok-jackson combo works, but it does not work here. I'm totally confused, this is unbelievelably ridiculous situation, where (unnecessary) simplification creates superb complexity. But I'd like to understand it, since I can encounted this situation in future again.

[Jackson Deserialization Fails because of non-default constructor created by lombok](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47598037/jackson-deserialization-fails-because-of-non-default-constructor-created-by-lomb)

So to have something easy to work with: here we have nice&working pure jackson:

```java
public class TestTO_pureJackson {
    private final String a;
    private final String b;

    @JsonCreator
    private TestTO_pureJackson(@JsonProperty("a") String a, @JsonProperty("b") String b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }
}
```

and here we have not working lombok equivalent (even if I remove one field, so that it's "same" to latter example):

```java
@lombok.Data
public class TestTO {
    private final String a;
    private final String b;

    @lombok.Builder(builderClassName = "Builder")
    private TestTO(String a, String b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    public static TestTO.Builder create(String a) {
        return builder().a(a);
    }
}
```

and we are trying to deserialize:

```js
{"a": "a", "b": "b"}
```

Can anyone understand the magic under the hood, and help me to understand what's wrong here?

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
  <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
  <version>1.18.2</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

And to make it even more ridiculous (do you actually see any significant difference with TestTO???), following code works:

```java
@lombok.Data
public class Pair {
    private final String left;
    private final String right;

    @lombok.Builder(builderClassName = "Builder")
    private Pair(String pairId) {
        left = pairId.substring(0, 3).toUpperCase(Locale.US);
        right = pairId.substring(3).toUpperCase(Locale.US);
    }
}
```

and main method:

```java
public class PairTest {

    public static final String DATA = "[\"btcusd\",\"ltcusd\",\"ltcbtc\"]";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Pair[] pairs = objectMapper.readValue(DATA, Pair[].class);

        for (Pair pair : pairs) {
            System.out.println(pair);
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone see, why 2 almost same TO classes behave differently?

Comment: Is there a `lombok.config` in any of the projects? If so, what are its contents?

Comment: yes:
config.stopBubbling=true
lombok.accessors.chain=true
but I was concerned that this can be caused by violating java bean spec, so I tried it also without lombok.accessors.chain=true, and it behaved the same.

Answer (score 3):

`TestTO` does not work because there is no constructor that Jackson can use. It cannot use the two-args constructor, because it does not know which JSON field should be used for which argument (because argument names are removed during compilation).
For lombok-generated constructors, you can work around that by advising Lombok to generate a `@ConstructorProperties` annotation. Just add

```
lombok.anyConstructor.addConstructorProperties=true
```

to your `lombok.config`. In your case of a manual constructor, you could also simply add the `@JsonProperty`s.
(Note that Jackson does not automatically use builders; you have to explicitly tell Jackson that with `@JsonDeserialize` and `@JsonPOJOBuilder`.)

`TestTO_pureJackson` works, because `@JsonProperty` is available at runtime and used by Jackson to determine the mapping.

`Pair` works, because there is a usable constructor: Jackson does not have to guess which parameter belongs to which field, because there is just one. Note that this only works for `String`, `int`, `long` or `boolean` one-arg constructors.
Lombok does *not* generate any additional constructor (here: the two-args constructor) if there is already one (see [documentation of `@Data`](https://projectlombok.org/features/Data)), so this is the only constructor on the class.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I mean very very much, it cleared things a lot. All works and I get all of that. Except one thing. OK, …addConstructorProperties must be set to true, and only after that, only constructors created by lombok will work with jackson. OK, got it. But provided Registration @Data class has explicitly declared 6 arg constructor, thus lombok wont create another constructor. And explicitly declared one has no jackson annotations. And yet it works — for them. Not for me. Full project: https://github.com/alfonz19/lombok-mystery
check the class ExplicitlyCreatedConstructor

Comment: I just checked it myself: `ExplicitlyCreatedConstructor` does *not* work for me, either. And that is what I would expect. Maybe they have an old Lombok version installed in Eclipse, causing different code to be generated?